# how to insert value from radio button into mysql using php

Tags: php

i have tried this code to insert value into database, but i don't Know why, the value was not send into the databases. The table i have created in the mysql :

```
    <?php
    require_once "connection.php";
        $conn = connect();
        $db = connectdb();

    mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die (mysql_error() . "\n");
    $query_usr = "select * from soalselidik";
    $usr = mysql_query($query_usr,$conn) or die(mysql_error()."\n".$query_usr);
    $row_usr=mysql_fetch_assoc($usr);

//to insert in database
    $a1=$_POST['a1'];
    $a2=$_POST['a2'];
    $a3=$_POST['a3'];
    $a4=$_POST['a4'];
    $b1=$_POST['b1'];
    $b2=$_POST['b2'];
    $b3=$_POST['b3'];
    $b4=$_POST['b4'];
    $c1=$_POST['c1'];
    $c2=$_POST['c2'];
    $c3=$_POST['c3'];
    $c4=$_POST['c4'];
    $d1=$_POST['d1'];
    $d2=$_POST['d2'];
    $d3=$_POST['d3'];
    $d4=$_POST['d4'];
    $e1=$_POST['e1'];
    $f1=$_POST['f1'];

    echo $query ="insert into soalselidik (a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,c1,c2,c3,c4,d1,d2,d3,d4,e1,f1) values('$a1','$a2','$a3','$a4','$b1','$b2','$b3','$b4','$c1','$c2','$c3','$c4''$d1','$d2','$d3','$d4','$e1','$f1')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<script languange = 'Javascript'>
                    alert('thankyou ! Penilaian anda diterima ');
                    location.href = 'home.php';</script>";

    ?>
```

Comment: Design databasenya masih belum baik.

Comment: Can you verify that it's actually making it into your `$_POST`? Perhaps add your HTML to the question? Also, I recommend using `mysqli` ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php ) or `PDO` ( http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php ) for more secure database querying.

Comment: You have 18 $_POSTed variables....which ones are inserting? Some or none?

Comment: add the HTML so we can solve your problem

Comment: Also, check you PHP error log to see if some of these posted vars are undefined...you should have a PHP warning or notice in your error log for these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'$c4''$d1'
```

Find that in your query and fix it :) And please do some error checking, and please stop using `MySQL_*` for your own good. Why should people not run any error checking mechanism that's already provided in the language and expect others to debug typos?

In case you didn't get it, there's a comma missing

**[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)**

Comment: I just want to second the "stop using `MySQL_*` because it's very important. It's been deprecated, and you're way safer using another method. I prefer PDO myself.